# only space in URL of a GET request in Rest causes 404

Tags: java, rest, spring-mvc, spring-restcontroller, spring-rest

Team,

I have created a search API and made it as GET request. Now when I try to give only a single space in search, it gives me 404 resource not found error.  For example:

```
http://localhost:8080/myproject/myapp/search/ ?pageNo=1&limit=20
```

As you can see there is a space in the URL after /search/. This URL returns me the error 404. I'm using Spring 4.x version.

Thanks

Comment: Why the space? URLs are not supposed to have them. If you need a space as a part of something else, use the hex value or a `+`: `https://www.google.com/?q=my+name`

Answer (score 2):

The URL is invalid with a space between the URL part and the request parameter string '?'. You need to encode the URL to replace characters like space with '%20'.

Try:

```
String encodedUrl = URLEncoder.encode(url, "UTF-8");
```

Comment: plus 1 for the aom avatar :)

Comment: Even after putting %20 between the URL and the request parameters, the request is not coming to the server.I mean I'm still getting 404 error.

Answer (score 0):

You can also `trim` all spaces before your query goes to request URL. Not sure that user need to have ability to **search by space** (nothing).

And using of `URLEncoder` for strings coming to URL is very recommended.